# Chef - Using Subversion Resource To Diff/Notify

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to figure out a way to use the Subversion resource in a Chef recipe to compare an existing file with the HEAD revision in a repository.

Right now it looks like the Subversion resource will just export the file, overwriting the existing file. This does not work for me, as I want to use this for service configuration files, and issue a restart if the file is different.

Currently I am exporting the current version from the repo to a temp file. Then I notify a bash resource to diff the files - if different, replace the existing file and restart the service. This is a lot of extra overhead, just to replicate the functionality of existing resources (ie. cookbook_file and template).

Note: I don't want to have to modify a file and then upload the cookbook every time there is a change. I need other admins to be able to modify config files without needing in-depth Chef knowledge.

Is this even possible using the Subversion resource? If not, is there another resource/method I could use to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after working this on for a while, I found I could not use the subversion resource for this. The subversion resource would always trigger the notify or overwrite the file.

I had to use the remote_file resource, using the SVN HTTP credentials.

My solution looked like this:

```
execute "service_restart" do
  command "restorecon /etc/path/configFile; service serviceName restart"

  action :nothing

  end

remote_file "/etc/path/configFile" do
  source "http://svnUser:svnPath@subversion.domain.net/repo/path/configFile"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0444

  notifies :run, "execute[service_restart]", :immediately

  end
```

NOTE: I know this is not the best way to restart the service, but I had to do it this way for this service. The general idea of using the remote_file resource is what is important though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use subversion, so apologies in advance.

The [subversion](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_subversion.html) resource in chef supports 4 actions. The documentation is not entirely clear but I wonder if one of these could be used to trigger a [notification](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_common.html#notifications) when the code changes:

```
subversion "My Project" do
  repository "http://svn.myorg/repos/myproject/trunk"
  revision "HEAD"
  destination "/opt/myproject"
  action :checkout
  notifies :restart, "service[helloworld]", :delayed
end
```